# The getAndIncrement implementation of AtomicInteger

Tags: java, synchronization, atomic, volatile

The getAndIncrement implementation of AtomicInteger does the following:

```
public final int getAndIncrement() {
    for (;;) {
        int current = get(); // Step 1 , get returns the volatile variable
        int next = current + 1;
        if (compareAndSet(current, next))
            return current;
    } }
```

Isn't it an equivalent of aVolatileVariable++? (which we know is not a correct usage). Without synchronization, how are we ensuring that this complete operation is atomic? What if the value of the volatile variable changes after the variable 'current' is read in Step 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "secret sauce" is in this call:

```
compareAndSet(current, next)
```

The [`compareAndSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#compareAndSet%28V,%20V%29) operation is going to fail (and return `false`) if the original volatile value has been changed concurrently *after* the read, forcing the code to continue with the loop.

Comment: Some ISAs (notably x86) provide atomic add (or fetch_add) directly, like ``mov eax, 1` ; `lock add [rdi], eax` (memory+=eax, and register = old value from memory).This doesn't require any retry loop, so it only has to wait to get exclusive access to the cache line (just like any store).    A good JVM will have an x86-specific implementation of this function.  See also [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](//stackoverflow.com/q/39393850).  But sure, you can synthesize arbitrary operations out of a CAS retry loop.

Comment: Of course, most non-x86 ISAs actually have LL/SC (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional)  rather than CAS (compare-and-swap) as their atomic primitive building block, so again a good JVM would make the implementation slightly more efficient and use an LL/SC retry loop around an add instead of using an actual CAS implemented in terms of LL/SC like you might get if you actually used this code.  But that's less of a big deal than avoiding a retry loop entirely on x86.